# Desktop running W7 64-bit Professional graphics issues

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I recently used IOBit Driver Booster to update a number of drivers on my PC, as well as a few "important" Windows updates.
Following a shutdown, on re-boot the next day, the display was corrupted — the size and aspect ratio settings were wrong (too big and stretched horizontaly), while the screen was not quite filled (this is the subject of another question of mine); it seems that the PC is simply not "seeing" mu plug-&-play Philips monitor.
OK, so that's the initial problem.
Since this happened, suddenly Google Earth will no longer run; it comes up with an error message that my graphics card (the same one I've always used!) is incompatible with GoogleEarth, and I should try restarting G.E. in another graphics mode; but when I do this, the display is totally awry. So it suggests I need to download the latest DirectX software and try again. This I have done, but still to no avail.

Thinking that my recent driver updates must be to blame, I tried to perform a system restore to a point before those updates — though I was only able to go back so far, I suspect posssibly not far enough.

To get me back to where I was at, I uninstalled Google Earth all over again (as I had done before — for some reason it was the "Pro" version) and then re-installed it, together with the DirectX update (again!)
But even with a clean installation, it still refuses to run normally.
Can anyone pelase point me to where I should start looking for the underlying cause of this and probably the other problem too — it seems to me that my attempt at updating the graphics card driver must be what has caused the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reinstall the old graphics driver?

Comment: Using driver updating products is a sure way to destroy your installation. But you already know that by now.

Comment: Thanks, David! I would, but I don't know where to find it, since presumably if I go and try to download it, I'll still get given the latest version. I don't know how to get back the old one!